# Comparar filas en un dataframe y detectar valores erroneos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con 40000 filas y quiero crear una función que me detecte los valores que tienen la misma diferencia con el valor anterior (N - N-1), que con sus dos anteriores (N-1 - N-2). Adjunto el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Time  Value1  Result   
1:10   4.23     0        
1:20   5.80     0        
1:30   6.12     0         
1:40   6.5      0         
1:50   6.6      0        
2:00   6.7      0         
2:10   6.8      0         
2:20   5        0         
2:30   5.3      0
```

Me gustaria que la columna result me devolviera 1 si ocurre lo anteriormente mencionado y que no cambie la columna si no ocurre:

```
Time  Value1  Result   
1:10   4.23     0        
1:20   5.80     0        
1:30   6.12     0         
1:40   6.5      0         
1:50   6.6      0        
2:00   6.7      1         
2:10   6.8      1         
2:20   5        0         
2:30   5.3      0
```

La libreria que estoy utilizando es pandas.

Comment: Sabemos lo que quieres, pero puedes poner lo que has intentado? Por norma general en StackOverflow no se aceptan opiniones o respuestas sujetas a subjetividad (Lo que pides se puede hacer de muchas formas y cada uno lo haría de forma diferente) Sin embargo si por ejemplo te faltara una coma, o tuvieras una operación errónea si que podríamos indicarte la solución a ese problema específico. Mira aquí para saber como hacer una buena pregunta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: El problema es que no he llegado a intentar nada, por que no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas, con su método `Series.diff()` te puede restar a cada elemento el anterior. Sobre tus datos saldría esto:

```
>>> df.Value1.diff()
     NaN
1    1.57
2    0.32
3    0.38
4    0.10
5    0.10
6    0.10
7   -1.80
8    0.30
```

Lo que pides en el fondo es, a partir de este resultado, detectar parejas de valores consecutivos iguales. Podemos volver a aplicar `.diff()` sobre el resultado anterior, y los elementos que sean 0 en el resultado nos identificarán dos datos iguales seguidos:

```
>>> df.Value1.diff().diff()
0             NaN
1             NaN
2   -1.250000e+00
3    6.000000e-02
4   -2.800000e-01
5    8.881784e-16
6   -8.881784e-16
7   -1.900000e+00
8    2.100000e+00
```

Aquí aparece un problema debido a redondeos en el punto flotante. Las filas 5 y 6 son prácticamente cero, y por tanto serían las que buscamos, pero no son *exactamente cero* debido ala forma en que opera el punto flotante. Así que no podemos compararlas con cero, sino por ejemplo tomar su valor absoluto y ver si éste es menor que un cierto umbral mínimo por debajo del cual consideraremos que ya son iguales:

```
>>> EPSILON = 1e-10
>>> df.Value1.diff().diff().abs() < EPSILON
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
```

Basta convertir esos booleanos a enteros y asignarlos a la columna que quieres:

```
df.Result = (df.Value1.diff().diff().abs() < EPSILON).astype(int)
```

El resultado es el buscado:

```
   Time  Value1  Result
0  1:10    4.23       0
1  1:20    5.80       0
2  1:30    6.12       0
3  1:40    6.50       0
4  1:50    6.60       0
5  2:00    6.70       1
6  2:10    6.80       1
7  2:20    5.00       0
8  2:30    5.30       0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Ahora tengo que hacerlo para todas las columnas, pero me imagino que no es complicado.

Comment: No habías dicho que tenías varias columnas... `diff()` puede operar sobre varias columnas a la vez, dandote como resultado varias columnas con las diferencias, pero no está claro qué iría entonces en la columna `Result` o si habría varias columnas `Result`

Comment: La idea es analizar todo el dataframe, y si en cualquiera de las columnas ocurriera(Value1, Value2, Value3...), result sería 1. Result sería una columna única.

Comment: Ah, creo que entiendo. Creo que la solución implica iterar por las columnas e ir haciendo operaciones booleanas entre las columnas-resultado (usando `|`), antes de pasar al final a entero la columna de booleanos resultante. Es posible que se pueda hacer también sin iterar, usando `.any()`. Si no das con ello haz otra pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo, lo intentare más tarde, muchas gracias!